# Jinja2 - Check to see if one query set elements are in another

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

So I have two query sets, I'm struggling to find a way to check if query set 1 has all it's elements in query set 2. Query set 2 has more elements than Query set 1 however but I just want to check if Query set 1 has all it's elements in the second.

Anyone know any solution to this?

So far I have used this in my jinja2 template

- Queryset 1 = group.dependancies
- Queryset 2 = SelectedGroups

But really I want it to display if the dependancies have been satisfied or not instead of simply listing the missing ones.

```
{% for dp in group.dependancies.all() %}
  {% if dp not in SelectedGroups.all() %}

    <p>Missing dependancy {{ dp }}</p>

  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this on the Jinja2 template, but wherever you are generating these querysets:

```
result =  all(item in list(group.dependancies.all()) for item in list(SelectedGroups.all()))
if result:
    msg = "<p>All dependencies satsfied.</p>"
else:
    msg = "<p>Dependencies missing.</p>
```

Then return msg to the template and render it with `{{msg}}`.

Comment: Thank you, I had a feeling I was looking at the problem in the wrong way.

Comment: @Jack Glad to help.  Try it out and let me know if it doesn't work for you.  If it does, the accept is always appreciated :)

Comment: Yeah the code you supplied came in handy, got it working, thanks again  :)